# CupertinoDatePicker results in flutter are printed before the date picker widget executes

Tags: flutter, datepicker

Code written after `CupertinoDatePicker` is executed before it.

I'm using `CupertinoDatePicker`, and facing this issue. Below code is an example that I have created to ask the question and find the solution from flutter experts. Any help to solve the issue will be appreciated.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

void main() => runApp(MyApp()); // Run class MyApp

// Context is where the widget is located in the app
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cupertinio Datepicker'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
            tooltip: 'Add Date',
            onPressed: () {
              print('1. Date Before : ${selectedDate} ');
              setState(() {
                _showModalBottomSheet(context);
              });
              print('3. Date After : ${selectedDate} ');
              // Problem: I have to call another page here with the changed date but date remains same and SecondPage is called before _showModalBottomSheet
              //navigateToSecondPage(context, selectedDate);


            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _showModalBottomSheet(context){
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
          child: _showCuperTinoDatePicker(),
        );
      }
  );
}


Widget _showCuperTinoDatePicker() {
  return CupertinoDatePicker(
    initialDateTime: selectedDate,
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
      selectedDate = newdate;
      print('2. onDateTimeChanged : ${selectedDate}' );
    },
    minimumYear: 2010,
    maximumYear: 2050,
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
  );
}
```

Expected results:

```
I/flutter (13818): 1. Date Before : 2019-08-29 00:00:00.000 
I/flutter (13818): 2. on Date Time Changed : 2019-08-30 00:00:00.000
I/flutter (13818): 3. Date After : 2019-08-30 00:00:00.000 
// go to next page
```

Actual Results: Here's the output of print statement

```
1. Date Before : 2019-08-29  [output of print statement]
3. Date After : 2019-08-29 [output of print statement]
// goes to next page, After closing the page, it comes back to first page and displays date picker
2. print 'on Date Time Changed' : 2019-08-30 00:00:00.000
2. print  'on Date Time Changed' : 2019-08-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please copy your code directly in the question rather than an external link.

Answer (score 1):

The problem stems from `_showModalBottomSheet()`, because inside it you use `showModalBottomSheet()` which returns a `Future`, and flutter finds an asynchronous function it continues executing other functions and displays the result when available.

One solution to your problem would be to use a `Button` to move to the next screen, because `CupertinoDatePicker` has no function to handle selection, only `onDateTimeChanged` :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

void main() => runApp(MyApp()); // Run class MyApp

// Context is where the widget is located in the app
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cupertinio Datepicker'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.add),
            tooltip: 'Add Date',
            onPressed: () {
              print('1. Date Before : $selectedDate ');
              setState(() {
                _showModalBottomSheet(context);
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Second Page'),
            onPressed: (){
              //navigateToSecondPage(context, selectedDate);
            }
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _showModalBottomSheet(context){
  showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context){
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith().size.height / 3,
          child: _showCupertinoDatePicker(),
        );
      }
  );
}


Widget _showCupertinoDatePicker() {
  return CupertinoDatePicker(
    initialDateTime: selectedDate,
    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDate) {
      selectedDate = newDate;
      print('2. onDateTimeChanged : $selectedDate' );
    },
    minimumYear: 2010,
    maximumYear: 2050,
    mode: CupertinoDatePickerMode.date,
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank You. Moving the _showModalBottomSheet and _showCupertinoDatePicker to second page worked. the problem is solved on android emulator and iPhone emulator but we faced another problem on iPhone TestFlight App.
 
Syntax to call second page:    selectDate = await Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => GetDatePage(context, selectDate,),),);  

We released the code to iPhone - TestFlight. As soon as we click the button that calls GetDatePage, iPhone app terminates with the error 'RangeError: Value not in range :20'.  What can be the reason?